# How to make my form full-width in mobile and certain width in desktop via bulma css?

Tags: css, bulma

this is my current HTML for display a form field with `bulma`.

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <nav class="navbar is-primary is-navbar-sticky">
    </nav>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <form>
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label is-medium">
              "Title"
              <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" class="input is-medium is-danger" placeholder="Put the title of item here" required="" value="">
                  <p class="help is-danger">title's length should be equal or greater than 10. Current: 0</p>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

So far so good.

A problem is that the `input` will take full width on each breakpoint, it's too much for a desktop resolution.

How to make the `input` only takes full width for mobile breakpoint while it could take a certain width after the mobile breakpoint.

Is there a `bulma` way to do this? Rather than write my own css rule?

Comment: responsive web design might help, despite the fact that you want bulma

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia Thanks for the advice, I just wanna know if the framework already handle that or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Your using bulma framework So assign grid system of bulma framework you can use class column in your input element and you can use how much column u you want to set width of input field

Comment: Thanks, saw that `columns` class, any example for using this class for achieving my goal?

Comment: `<div class="control">
    <input type="text" class="input columns-12 is-medium is-danger" placeholder="Put the title of item here" required="" value="">
    <p class="help is-danger">title's length should be equal or greater than 10. Current: 0</p>
 </div>`

Comment: add these lines check

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="control">
   <input type="text" class="input column-12 is-medium is-danger" 
          placeholder="Put the title of item here" required="" value="">
   <p class="help is-danger">title's length should be equal or greater than 10. Current: 0</p>
</div>
```